# Hibernate Session Closed Exception after fast subsequent requests

Tags: hibernate, session, wicket

I get a `Caused by: org.hibernate.SessionException: Session is closed!` error when I click on a link before the whole page is loaded (or my guess, just inside the active hibernate session).

All of my DAO classes are subclassing `GenericDAO` where i got this method:

```
public Session getSession() {
    if (session == null || !session.isOpen()) {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    }
    return session;
}
```

This is called from:

```
public void beginTransaction() {
    transaction = getSession().beginTransaction();
}
```

and finally commited:

```
public void commit() {
    if (transaction != null)
        transaction.commit();
    transaction = null;
    session = null;
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you use a single instance of your DAO for all requests. However, your DAO tries to store the current `Session` in its field, therefore it cannot handle concurrent requests. Note that `Session` is not thread-safe and you should use different `Session`s for different requests.

Actually, your complex logic in `getSession()` method is not needed. When you need a current `Session` in your DAO, you can just write `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()`. As long as Hibernate is properly configured (see [2.3. Contextual sessions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/architecture.html#architecture-current-session)), it will return the correct instance of the current session, and your DAO will be able to serve concurrent queries.

Comment: Thanks a lot, thread-unsafe it was. I changed my code and since then I couldn't reproduce the exception while madly clicking all the links. Btw, I got the getSession()-method from a DAO/POJO-creator tool...